# How can I load the components of different users in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, components

On my computer are 2 windows users (one of them is me).
Both of them are delphi developers. I'm the new one. I need to get the components he used. 
How can I move, export or copy his components and save or import them to my windows account ?

Comment: While the other user is logged in, export the registry keys for Delphi (HKCU\Software\Borland\Delphi X and HKLM\Software\Borland\Delphi X, where X is the version number). Then log in as yourself and import the registry files.

Comment: You need to get everything under revision control

Comment: there is no folder named Borland under HKCU\Software in other user's account. but there is a folder in Program Files but i dont know if it can be a solution for me?

Comment: When you get a component, put it under revision control. Then all you need is to checkout and build.